# How can I use 'Nook for android' to read non-latin encoding epub books normally?

Tags: nook-for-android

I installed Nook for android on my P1010. When I use it to read English epub book, no problem. But when I read a Chinese book with GB2312 encoding, there are lots of irrecognizable characters. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

> According to page 36 of the NOOK User Guide, the NOOK supports fonts with Latin character sets.  Other font types can only be viewed if they are embedded in the document.

Extracted from [Does Nook support Chinese/Japanese?](http://bookclubs.barnesandnoble.com/t5/NOOK-Technical-Support/Does-Nook-support-Chinese-Japanese/td-p/556575)

You might also want to take a look at this workaround: [Font Changes](http://nookdevs.com/Font_Changes)